# Начертания шрифта

Tags: html, css, шрифты

Есть шрифт Tahoma:

```
font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;
```

Хочу проставить у некоторого элемента значение

```
{
   font-family: Tahoma
   font-weight: 900
}
```

и получаю один вариант шрифта.

Если подключить Tahoma-Bold:

```
font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;
```

и для этого же элемента проставить

```
{
   font-family: Tahoma-Bold
}
```

То в 2 вариантов отобразится шрифт разной толщины.

Всегда думал, что Жирное начертание = Нормальное начертание + font-weight: 900

[image] - Tahoma-Bold

[image] - Tahoma, font-weight: 900

Comment: Не понял фразы «в 2 вариантов». Вообще, можете привести [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/TZ659QT.jpg - шрифт при Tahoma-Bold

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/7jlqhQC.jpg - шрифт при Tahoma, font-weight: 900

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Во-первых, жирностей шрифта теоретически не 3, а 9: 100, 200, 300, 400 (normal), 500, 600, 700 (bold), 800, 900. Во-вторых, bold - это не 900, а 700.

Далее, подключая новый веб-шрифт, ты должен указать его жирность. Если у тебя подключены только некоторые из жирностей, то как должен поступить браузер, если ему вдруг попадётся неподключенная? Он либо выберет ближайшую, либо попытается сам подогнать шрифт под запрошенную жирность. А как он может подогнать? Просто что-нибудь растянет. А как подгоняли авторы шрифта? Они полностью рисовали каждую букву, чтобы она хорошо смотрелась в этой жирности. А может ещё и лигатуры рисовали. Вот и получается два разных начертания.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0ks93x79/ - я могу так подключать шрифты -  одно название но разные начертания?

Comment: То есть в момент когда у шрифта нет начертания шрифта,  браузер сам решает как его увеличивать, я правильно понял?

Comment: @ruslik, да, можешь так - одно имя, разные веса и файлы. Браузер сам решает, увеличивать или нет - думаю, зависит от браузера.